# How does the UART communication detect the true idle in this case?

Tags: uart, serial

When explaining UART communication it is told that the receiver will start sampling the data one start bit after the first falling edge. The falling edge occurs when TX goes from idle state to zero as shown follows:

[image]

So normally above the receiver listens the TX line and when it detects idle voltage goes to zero the sampling starts one bit after.

What is not clear to me is that imagine the following scenario where the receiver is turned on and started to listen the TX line at the point I marked in red below(on the leftmost):

[image]

In this case will the receiver think(interpret) bit1 and bit2 as idle and the first byte will be received wrong?

Comment: Your opening sentence is incorrect. It will sample 1.5 bits after the first falling edge.

Comment: Yes, and I have seen it happen if I send the same pattern and unplug then re-plug the cable.

Comment: @Andyaka Is the start bit duration 1.5 times longer than the data bit duration?

Comment: @Andyaka Oh I see what you mean it samples at the middle of the data bit so it becomes 1.5.

Comment: @Genzo correct.

Comment: it is perfectly valid to have all 8 bits in this case high, that is a 0xFF byte or (0x7F with parity).  likewise they can all be zero 0x00 it drops at the start bit and goes back up for the stop bit.  it wouldnt make sense if you couldnt have your bit pattern end with 0b011.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will misinterpret things.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn the receiver on after the start of a data word, then of course, the receiver will not interpret it correctly. You could regard this as misusing, rather than using a link.

If the word is immediately followed by a further word, then the misalignment can continue. As long as bit 2 is 1 and bit 3 is zero, the RX will 'see' a start edge at the time it expects.

It's only when there's a pause in the transmission for long enough, so idle time of one word duration, that the RX is guaranteed to properly be able to synchronise to the start of the next word.

If a communication system is to be designed so that it can be plugged in after a transmission has started, then the protocol will have to be designed so that words can be missed, potentially garbled words are validated with, for instance, checksums, and pauses are allowed for resynchronisation. Without these precautions, a misused serial comms link could potentially misbehave forever.

Comment: What do you mean by misused serial comms? Since we cannot change the protocol settings or hardware, do you mean by using in our coding(such as firmware C code) we should eliminate it? Quote "so idle time of one word duration," Can that be modified if we have a UART chip?

Comment: @genzo He just means it's not designed to not garble messages when plugged in mid-message.

Comment: to put it another way - a serial transmission without gaps between bytes is designed to be garbled if you switch on mid word. A serial transmission without CRC or other forward error control is designed to not be able to detect the garbling.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a chance that the system may not detect it as an error. It will simply further sample the idle line and assume stop condition and stop.

The first byte if reported as error, can be cleared in software and the rest of the bytes will be received properly. Hence, in general there will be CRC or error checking mechanism to make sure that the wrongly interpreted messages will not considered.

As soon as there is an idle time of about one complete word.. the system will be ready to receive error free. One word I meant - start bury stop bit and 8 bit of data..